# What is the most efficient way to use a wrapper for an object in Java?

Tags: java, interface

I am going to use an external search engine in my application. I am defining EngineInterface as follows:

```
public interface IEngineInterface{
public abstract List<Result> search(String q);
}
```

Result class:

```
public Class Result{
   A a;
   B b;
}
```

And the Engine class is like this:

```
public Class Engine implements IEngineInterface{
private static ExternalEngine e = new ExternalEngine;
@override
public List<Result> search(String q) {
   return wrapper(e.search(q));
}
```

The fact is that e.search doesn't return `List<Result>` and it returns `List<ExternalResult>` and I put the wrapper function which goes over each individual list item and convert it. What is the best way for solving this issue? I'm defining my own Result class to have the flexibility to change the ExternalEngine later.

Comment: I don't understand... What **does** `e.search()` return?

Comment: It is up to you to loop through `List<ExternalResult>` and transform it to `List<Result>`

Comment: Does `ExternalResult` extend the `Result` class? If so, you could make `search` return a `List<? extends Result>`.

Comment: @nbokmans no I don't have any access to `ExternalResult` class and it doesn't extend `Result` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java 8:

```java
public List<Result> search(String q) {
    List<ExternalResult‌​> exResults = e.search(q);
    List<Result> results = exResults.stream().map((x) -> new Result(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return results;
}
```

You need to implement a constructor for `Result` that takes an `ExternalResult` as an argument to do the conversion.

Answer (score 3):

You are on track, your approach is not Polymorphic enough though.

Consider:

```
    public interface IExternalEngineSearch
    {
       public List<ExternalResult> search(String q);
       public List<Result> parseExternalResult(List<ExternalResult> q);
    }

    public class ExternalEngineSearch implements IExternalEngineSearch
    {
       @override 
       public List<ExternalResult> search(String q){}

       @override
       public List<Result> parseExternalResult(List<ExternalResult> q){}
    }
```

Result class:

```
  public Class ExternalResult
  {
     A a;
     C c;
     B b;
  }

  public Class Result{
     A a;
     B b;
  }
```

And the Engine class is like this:

```
  public interface IEngineInterface{
    public abstract List<Result> search(String q);
  }

  public Class Engine implements IEngineInterface{
  private static ExternalEngineSearch e = new ExternalEngineSearch;
  @override
  public List<Result> search(String q) {
     return e.parseExternalResult(e.search(q));
  }
```

And instead of instantiating the class `ExternalEngineSearch` within the `Engine` class you can consider using the [Factory Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to create your external classes, which can help u add more external search engines to your implementation when needed. Your code remains clean, simple and maintainable.

Like:

```
  public Class Engine implements IEngineInterface{
  private static IExternalEngineSearch e = ExternalEngineSearchFactory.create(ExternalEngineSearchType.Google);
  @override
  public List<Result> search(String q) {
     return e.parseExternalResult(e.search(q));
  }
```

I hope I was clear enough?

Answer (score 2):

```
public List<Result> search(String q) {
    List<Result> resultList = new ArrayList<Result>();
    for (ExternalResult exresult : e.search(q)) {
      resultList.add(new Result(exresult));
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

This would be the simplest way...

Comment: in java **in** needs to be replaced with **:**